# call shared library from shared library - works in C but crash with python (ctypes)

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, opencl, ctypes

I'm calling function `clGetPlatformIDs()` from `libOpenCL` library inside my own library `lib_fft3d`.

- When I write an application which use `lib_fft3d.so` in C language
  and run it, it works just fine.
- However, when I try to load `lib_fft3d.so` in python using `ctypes.CDLL` and than run a function wrapping `clGetPlatformIDs()` it crash with segmentation fault.

The truble is I don't see any error message like e.g. *undefined reference*, so I'm clueless where can be the problem.

Follows the minimal code reproducing the issue. It can be also [downloaded](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vu5omwfpe6yy2ph/AABCg0Dr49a9ibt1pdAd8vs1a?dl=0) from my dropbox. Or you can also see the [original version](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6a2hpv6hsbozedz/AAB3cOTan5PmBFobAMalooe9a?dl=0) which actually does something meaningfull (runs fast fourier transform using opencl).

**run.sh**

```
# /bin/bash

LPATH=/usr/local/lib64/
LPATH2=`pwd`
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$LPATH:$LPATH2
echo  $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

echo "========= Compile  libfft3d.so "
gcc -c -Wall -fpic -o lib_fft3d.o lib_fft3d.c
gcc -shared -o libfft3d.so lib_fft3d.o -lOpenCL

echo "========= C  use_fft3d.x "
gcc use_fft3d.c -o use_fft3d.x -L./ -lfft3d
./use_fft3d.x

echo "========= Python py_clfft.py "
python3 py_clfft.py
```

**lib_fft3d.h**

```
void initOCL();
```

**lib_fft3d.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include "lib_fft3.h"

cl_int err;
char platform_name[128];
char device_name[128];
cl_platform_id platform = 0;
cl_device_id device = 0;
cl_command_queue queue = 0;
cl_context ctx = 0;
cl_context_properties props[3] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, 0, 0 };

void initOCL(){
    printf("DEBUG 1.0 \n");
    err = clGetPlatformIDs( 1, &platform, NULL );      printf("DEBUG 1.1 \n");
    size_t ret_param_size = 0;

    err = clGetPlatformInfo(platform, CL_PLATFORM_NAME,sizeof(platform_name), platform_name, &ret_param_size);   printf("DEBUG 1.2 \n");
    printf("Platform found: %s\n", platform_name);
    err = clGetDeviceIDs( platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &device, NULL );                        printf("DEBUG 1.3 \n");
    err = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME,sizeof(device_name), device_name,&ret_param_size);    printf("DEBUG 1.4 \n");
    printf("Device found on the above platform: %s\n", device_name);
    props[1] = (cl_context_properties)platform;
    ctx   = clCreateContext( props, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err );    printf("DEBUG 1.5 \n");
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue( ctx, device, 0, &err );            printf("DEBUG 1.6 \n");
}
```

**use_fft3d.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lib_fft3.h"

int main( void ){
    printf( "DEBUG 1 \n" );
    initOCL();                      printf( "DEBUG 2 \n" );
    return 0;
}
```

**py_clfft.py**

```
import ctypes as ct

lib  = ct.CDLL(  "./libfft3d.so", ct.RTLD_LOCAL )

lib.initOCL.argtypes  = [ ] 
lib.initOCL.restype   =  None
def initOCL():
    lib.initOCL( )

initOCL()
```

The output is following:

```
========= C  use_fft3d.x 
DEBUG 1 
DEBUG 1.0 
DEBUG 1.1 
DEBUG 1.2 
Platform found: NVIDIA CUDA
DEBUG 1.3 
DEBUG 1.4 
Device found on the above platform: GeForce GTX 960M
DEBUG 1.5 
DEBUG 1.6 
DEBUG 2 
========= Python py_clfft.py 
DEBUG 1.0 
./run.sh: line 19:  9071 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 py_clfft.py
```

Comment: I think python itself is also exporting the `platform` symbol, which will be solved if you just make your variables static, so they won't be exported.

Comment: Or just add an attribute to the variables to be hidden if you don't need them exported.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, your comment is potentially helpful, but I don't understand what you suggest. What attribute should I add where in the code? (I have no background in this, I do it with trial and error)

Comment: either add `static` before your variables declared outside of you functions, or use [hidden visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) to prevent python from messing those variables up, like `platform` which may be pointing to somewhere else entirely and causing the segfault.

Comment: WOW, perfect I added `static` in front of all global variables and NOW IT WORKS. Thank you a lot!!! I started to understand what you mean. Basically the problem that definition of variable  `cl_platform_id platform = 0;` in the library is colliding with some variable defined in python. I wonder how you realized this, I would never think about this.

Comment: @AhmedAEK : if you bother to make your comment into regular answer, I will gladly give you up-vote and accept it as the answer, so that I can close the topic. Thanks again ! :D